# how can i default values for scraped result when they have a return of null/none

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have scraped some informations from a website in which some outputs are not present and it returns null. is there a way to output a default value in such case for different fields. The sample script is below.

script.py

```
import scrapy

class UfcscraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ufcscraper'

    start_urls = ['http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a']

    def parse(self, response):
        for user_info in response.css(".b-statistics__table-row")[2::]:
            result = {
                "fname": user_info.css("td:nth-child(1) a::text").get(),
                "lname": user_info.css("td:nth-child(2) a::text").get(),
                "nname": user_info.css("td:nth-child(3) a::text").get(),
                "height": user_info.css("td:nth-child(4)::text").get().strip(),
                "weight": user_info.css("td:nth-child(5)::text").get().strip(),
                "reach": user_info.css("td:nth-child(6)::text").get().strip(),
                "stance": user_info.css("td:nth-child(7)::text").get().strip(),
                "win": user_info.css("td:nth-child(8)::text").get().strip(),
                "lose": user_info.css("td:nth-child(9)::text").get().strip(),
                "draw": user_info.css("td:nth-child(10)::text").get().strip()
            }

        yield result
```

For instance nname field in the first row has a value of null while stance has a value of "", which is an empty string or so, how can i have a default value for such occurrences.

sample result

```
[
{"fname": "Tom", "lname": "Aaron", "nname": null, "height": "--", "weight": "155 lbs.", "reach": "--", "stance": "", "win": "5", "lose": "3", "draw": "0"},
{"fname": "Danny", "lname": "Abbadi", "nname": "The Assassin", "height": "5' 11\"", "weight": "155 lbs.", "reach": "--", "stance": "Orthodox", "win": "4", "lose": "6", "draw": "0"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either put in the logic to replace any "" in your function or you could just loop through the result and when you come across `""` replaqce with whatever you'd like as the default.

```
data = [
{"fname": "Tom", "lname": "Aaron", "nname": "", "height": "--", "weight": "155 lbs.", "reach": "--", "stance": "", "win": "5", "lose": "3", "draw": "0"},
{"fname": "Danny", "lname": "Abbadi", "nname": "The Assassin", "height": "5' 11\"", "weight": "155 lbs.", "reach": "--", "stance": "Orthodox", "win": "4", "lose": "6", "draw": "0"},
]


for idx, each in enumerate(data):
    for k, v in each.items():
        if v == '':
            data[idx][k] = 'DEFAULT'
```

**Output:**

```
print(data)
[
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Aaron', 'nname': 'DEFAULT', 'height': '--', 'weight': '155 lbs.', 'reach': '--', 'stance': 'DEFAULT', 'win': '5', 'lose': '3', 'draw': '0'}, 
{'fname': 'Danny', 'lname': 'Abbadi', 'nname': 'The Assassin', 'height': '5\' 11"', 'weight': '155 lbs.', 'reach': '--', 'stance': 'Orthodox', 'win': '4', 'lose': '6', 'draw': '0'}
]
```